# Zeros of a UCOCS limit of analytic Functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

By **Hurwitz's Theorem**, I mean the following statement:

> If the functions $f_n$ are analytic (holomorphic) in a region $D$,
>   have no zeros in $D$, and converge in $D$ to $f$, uniformly on each
>   compact subset, then either $f\equiv 0$ or $f$ has no zeros in $D$.

According to R.P. Boas, *Invitation to Complex Analysis,* pg. 110, we should also have

> ...the zeros of $f$ in $D$ are limits of sequence of zeros of $\{f_n\}$.

I'm not exactly sure how to show this second part. Maybe Rouche?

---

Edit: After thinking about it some more, I think the second statement follows from Rouche's theorem using the same argument for the proof of Hurwitz's Theorem. (Once again, it appears that I misunderstood the text as saying that the second part follows from Hurwitz.)

The outline of the proof is as follows:

It is sufficient to show that for any open set $U$ around a zero of $f$, there is a zero of $\{ f_n\}$.

Suppose that $f$ is not identically zero. Let $c$ be so that $f(c) = 0$. Let $U$ be any open set containing $c$.

Take $|z-c|<r$, so that $c$ is the only zero of $f$ in $|z-c|\le r$ and the interior of the circle belongs to $U$.  Then for sufficiently large $n$,

$|f - f_n| < \min |f| $, where the minimum is taken over the circle $|z-c|=r$.

By Rouche's theorem, there is at least one zero of $f_n$ in $|z-c|<r$.

Comment: You should state the hypotheses for the second claim.

Comment: I guess same as the statement of the Hurwitz's theorem, except the "no zeros" part. I mean, I am more or less copying word-for-word from the book.